# how to incorporate font awesome in a dart component?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

The following html displays a nice camera icon to the left of the text. When trying to style polymer components, how is this achieved?

```dart
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" id="font-awesome-4-css" href="http://astronautweb.co/wp-content/themes/astro2012/css/font-awesome-4.0.3.css?ver=4.0.3" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
  <p><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> Cool camera</p>
</body>
```

Specifically, where should the link be included, what should applyauthorstyles be set to, what should *style* within the template be.

Comment: This issue should have useful information for you: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12434

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

`applyAuthorStyles` is deprecated or already removed.

I haven't tried it myself yet, but it should work if the font-awesome styles are added to the component. This is cumbersome because the styles need to be added to each component where FA is used.

Pixelate uses SASS with these variables: https://github.com/donny-dont/Pixelate-Flat/blob/master/lib/stylesheets/fonts/_variables.scss
I haven't used SASS yet so I can't provide more details.

Another solution is to add `* /deep/` in front of each selector.

You can use this code to build a script that does this:

```dart
import 'package:csslib/parser.dart';
import 'package:csslib/visitor.dart';

String transform(String src){
  var printer = new ShadowDOMTransformPrinter();
  printer.visitTree(parse(src), pretty: true);
  return printer.toString();
}

class ShadowDOMTransformPrinter extends CssPrinter {
  void visitSelector(Selector selector){
    emit(' * /deep/ ');
    super.visitSelector(selector);
  }
}
```

This modified CSS doesn't work outside the shadowDOM therefor the modified and unmodified styles are needed (each selector once with and once without `/deep/`

See also [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!searchin/web/font%2420awesome/web/RAC8nE7DfTI/P4a8nlXMZjAJ) and [this one](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!searchin/web/%242Fdeep%242F%2420jmesserly/web/8bjmkiRFhDk/ba-IQmYoVmoJ)

**-------**

if you have the stylesheet reference at the page you need
`bool get applyAuthorStyles => true;`
in your custom element.

Referencing the stylesheet in the custom element had a bug as stated above.
The bug is fixed but the Dart version containing the fix is not yet released.

In the meantime you can copy the contents of the stylesheet in a style tag inside the custom element `<template>`.
In this case you won't need `applyAuthorStyles`.

Comment: `applyAuthorStyles` is [deprecated](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/polymer-dev/OJtrbA8ZBfM/kd1GCWapeCkJ).

Comment: So what is the new fix? The applyAuthorStyles fixed it - now with latest polymer back to no fonts showing up.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the [See also threads] you mentioned I followed up with my issue/misunderstanding with what you suggest in that thread. Maybe I should have find a way to offer a bounty to someone to just show me how it can work in my specific project on github. If you could revisit that thread and reply that would be awesome.

Comment: I use just handwritten CSS and haven't used any of these methods myself yet. When you post a question here or the Dart Web Development group I will see it and try to help and probably others too (if your repo is public).

Answer (score 6):

**Edit: Workaround for CSS variables:**

The font awesome CSS file includes an @font-face definition which does not currently work in the shadowDOM, at least in Chrome ([ref1](http://robdodson.me/blog/2013/11/19/at-font-face-doesnt-work-in-shadow-dom/), [ref2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/UUwew3x82EU)).  One way around this is to move the @font-face definition out of the fa CSS file and place it as a global style tag.  For example:

```dart
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        src: url('font-awesome-4.0.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
        src: url('font-awesome-4.0.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font-awesome-4.0.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'), url('font-awesome-4.0.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'), url('font-awesome-4.0.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
      }
    </style>
    <script type='application/dart'>export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

You can then reference a local copy of the edited fa CSS file internal to your custom polymer element with no need to use `applyAuthorStyles` like this:

```dart
<polymer-element name="dropdown-menu-element">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
```

Make sure you have downloaded the entire fa directory to your project.  The fa icons can now be used in your polymer element.

**Original Answer using applyAuthorStyles:**

I just include the path to font awesome in the head section of the index.html file:

```dart
<head>
    <title>Working with Polymer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-4.0.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="import" href="elements/navbar_element.html">
    <script type='application/dart'> export 'package:polymer/init.dart'; </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then in my `navbar_element.html` file, I just reference the icons the way you normally would:

```dart
<polymer-element name="navbar-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      /* other styles here */
      }
    </style>
    <div>
      <div class="st-container">
        <nav class="st-nav">
          <template repeat="{{item in menu}}" >
            <a id={{item.id}} href="#" class={{item.arrowClass}} on-click="{{menuHandler}}">
              <span class="menuName">{{item.text}}&nbsp;</span>
              <i class={{item.icon}}></i>
            </a>
          </template>
          <div class="arrow_box"></div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="navbar_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

In this case, I am referencing the specific font awesome icon, `<i class={{item.icon}}></i>`, in my navbar_element.dart file using an observable list like so:

```dart
final ObservableList<Item> menu =
      toObservable([
                    new Item('Fourier', 'fourier', 'fa fa fa-sort-amount-desc fa-rotate-270', false),
                    new Item('Sequences', 'sequence', 'fa fa-tasks', false),
                    new Item('Convolution', 'convolution', 'fa fa-asterisk', true),
                    new Item('Deconvolution', 'deconvolution', 'fa fa-headphones fa-rotate-90', false),
                    new Item('Filters', 'filter', 'fa fa-filter', false)
                    ]);
```

where the `icon` field is just a field in the `Item` class and I've set `bool get applyAuthorStyles => true;`.

Comment: Thanks. If I: (1) put the font-awsome link in top level html (2) in the component add a line like `<p><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>Picture annotated text</p>` and (3) put the same line in top level body near my component, my hope was a picture would be beside the text for both. It is for top level instance, but the not one in component. Is the code you are referencing open source on github/pub? You saying it works? Sounds like my issues may be related to the bug pointed out by Dennis - not sure. I'm on build 30187.

Comment: The app is a definitely a work in progress (ie, it's messy), but I've not had any issue with the icons, at least in Dartium - I have not checked in js.  The library is [here](https://github.com/scribeGriff/convolve_polymer) and the element I showed above is [here](https://github.com/scribeGriff/convolve_polymer/tree/master/web/elements).  I added a screenshot to the readme showing how I am using the fa icons.  Your application could certainly be different.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I have not figured my problem out yet - will keep searching. But your project is very attractive - so I have more to study. Thanks!

Comment: For what it is worth (my own experience): I imported FontAwesome from CDN in my main page (index.html) and just used the <i> element in my polymer elements. I couldn't see the icons in Dartium, but I saw them after building the application in Chrome and Firefox (current versions). After adding `@override bool get applyAuthorStyles => true;` to each PolymerElement using icons, I could see them in Dartium as well. Thanks to this questions and answers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems this package is doing exactly this
http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fontawesome_elements

I published the package [bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg) that makes FontAwesome icons compatible with core-elements and paper-elements

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide on styling polymer elements here which may be helpful:

http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html

Bascially it says you should use :host inside your template.