# font-awesome in <span> for polymer ">0.10.0"

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Now that applyAuthorStyles is deprecated the font-awesome icons no longer show up. This question [how to incorporate font awesome in a dart component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026280/how-to-incorporate-font-awesome-in-a-dart-component) has some useful information but I'm unable to get the untested suggestions to work.

Here is a template from a very simple mortgage calculator component project:

```dart
<polymer-element name="plus-payment-schedule">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Payment Schedule</legend>
        <label><span class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw" style="width:1.5em"></span> Start Date</label>
        <plus-date-input id="date"></plus-date-input>
        <div class="payment-schedule">
          <table id="schedule_table">
          </table>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="payment_schedule.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Prior to polymer 0.10.0, using the suggested *applyAuthorStyles* patch this code worked. Meaning, by applying those font-awesome classes (*class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"*) the font-awesome icons showed up. I've removed *applyAuthorStyles* and made other polymer init changes required for the update. The component works fine except the font-awesome icons no longer show up.

When I run this mortgage calculator app and look in the inspector, I see that those classes are applied to the span. So I guess the issue is the definition of the classes (fa fa-calendar fa-fw) is not available?

Any information on how to make this specific scenario work?

The component is hosted [here](https://github.com/patefacio/finance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

applyAuthorStyles is deprecated. Thus you have to include stylesheets within `<template>`.

The problem is that `@font-face` does not work inside polymer elements at the moment. The solution is to include `@font-face` in the regular document and to add the classes to your polymer or include font-awesome.css in both places.

This should solve it.

See also:
- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18581
- https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/434

Regards, Robert

Comment: I'm not having luck with either. Lets go with *including font-awesome.css in both places*. First I add the folder font-awesome-4.1.0 to my package's lib folder. Then, I put this line:

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="packages/mortgage_calculator/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css">

in <head> of my .../examples/mortgage_calculator.html top file and also just before the <polymer-element...> in the component. Is this the suggestion for the *or* part of your answer?

Comment: Ok I think I get it. The link statement must be inside the <template> element but not inside the <style> element, just before it.

Comment: Yes, of course :) <style> only holds text. <link/> in <template> is fine!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Font-Awesome Polymer Iconset](https://github.com/philya/font-awesome-polymer-icons) or generate your own subset using [this generator](https://github.com/philya/font-awesome-polymer-icons-generator)

You'll be able to use FA in core-icons and other icon based elements, like this:

```
<core-icon icon="fa:calendar"></core-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an element for that.

Use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontawesome-iconset:

1. get the icons you need from `fa-icons.html`
2. put it in a new `iron-iconset-svg`
3. import `iron-iconset-svg` and `iron-icon`
4. use it like other `iron-icon`

You can view how to use here: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icon

Comment: Or https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg then you don't need to use npm